# Why calling super from protocol gives an error?

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, uiviewcontroller, protocols

```
import UIKit

public protocol NibInitializable {
    init()
}

extension NibInitializable where Self: UIViewController {
    public init() {
        super.init(nibName: String(describing: Self.self), bundle: Bundle(for: Self.self))
    }
}
```

is the above code valid? I am getting the following error.
**'super' cannot be used outside of class members**
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

How can I implement such a logic.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/igkL9.png

Comment: Initializers are tricky. Make this a factory instead.

Answer (score 2):

Replace super with self :

```
  public protocol NibInitializable {
        init()
    }
    
    extension NibInitializable where Self: UIViewController {
        public init() {
            self.init(nibName: String(describing: Self.self), bundle: Bundle(for: Self.self))
        }
    }
```

Comment: if we replace super with self then I have to implement the init() function in each UIViewController which conforms to this protocol.

Comment: Why? That is one of the standard initialisers that all UIViewControllers have

Comment: but I do not wish to repeat the same code in each view controller. i.e. 
```init(nibName: String(describing: Self.self), bundle: Bundle(for: Self.self)) {

        super.init(nibName: String(describing: Self.self), bundle: Bundle(for: Self.self))

    }```

I need something written once.